# Related name returning post.commentpost.none

Tags: django, post, django-queryset

Can anyone explain me, why i get Post.CommentPost.None?

How to correct connect CommentPost with Posty in query? I need get {{posty.comments.user}} my result is Post.CommentPost.None

Here something about my models and functions.

```
class Posty(models.Model):
   title = models.CharField(max_length=250, blank=False, null=False, unique=True)
   sub_title = models.SlugField(max_length=250, blank=False, null=False, unique=True)
   content = models.TextField(max_length=250, blank=False, null=False)
   image = models.ImageField(default="avatar.png",upload_to="images", validators=[FileExtensionValidator(['png','jpg','jpeg'])])
   author = models.ForeignKey(Profil, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
   published = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
   T_or_F = models.BooleanField(default=False)
   likes = models.ManyToManyField(Profil, related_name='liked')
   unlikes = models.ManyToManyField(Profil, related_name='unlikes')
   created_tags = models.ForeignKey('Tags', blank=True, null=True, related_name='tagi', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
  test_wyswietlenia = models.IntegerField(default=0, null=True, blank=True)

class CommentPost(models.Model):
   user = models.ForeignKey(Profil, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   post = models.ForeignKey(Posty, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="comments")
   content1 = models.TextField(max_length=250, blank=False, null=False)
   date_posted = models.DateTimeField(default=timezone.now)
   date_updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

VIEWS

```
     tag = request.GET.get('tag')
   if tag == None:
       my_tag = Posty.objects.prefetch_related('comments')
       my_view = Posty.objects.prefetch_related('my_wyswietlenia')

   else:
      my_tag = Posty.objects.filter(created_tags__tag=tag)
      my_view = Posty.objects.prefetch_related('my_wyswietlenia')
```

TEMPLATES

```
                {% for post in my_tag %}
                  {% if post.comments.last.user == None %}
                    <span class="forum_tag_author">Komentarz » <a href="{% url 'home:detail_post' post.pk %}">Brak komentarza</a></span><br/>
                    <span class="forum_tag_author">Stworzony przez » <a href="{% url 'profile:profil_uzytkownika' post.pk %}">{{post.author}} </a> </span><hr/>
                  {% else %}
                    <span class="forum_tag_author">Komentarz » <a href="{% url 'home:detail_post' post.pk %}">{{post.comments.last.content1}}</a></span><br/>
                    <span class="forum_tag_author">Odpowiadający » <a href="{% url 'profile:profil_uzytkownika' post.pk %}">Dodany przez: {{post.comments.last.user}} </a> </span><hr/>
                  {% endif %}
              {% endfor %}
```

And this
{{post.comments}} give a request Post.CommentPost.None

What is problem? What i do bad?

Comment: `.comments` is a manager, you can use `{{ post.comments.all }}`, but I would advise annotating the queryset in the view to obtain the last author and `content1` faster.

Comment: When i do this, i got all list of comments. When i only need, post name, last post, user who add last comment to post

Comment: sure, that is why you need to annotate instead of prefetching.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a [**`Subquery`** expression [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/expressions/#subquery-expressions) to obtain the latest `content1` comment and author with:

```
from django.db.models import OuterRef, Subquery

last_comment = CommentPost.objects.filter(post=OuterRef('pk')).order_by('-date_posted')

my_tag = Posty.objects.annotate(
    last_comment=Subquery(last_comment.values('content1')[:1]),
    last_comment_user=Subquery(last_comment.values('user__name')[:1]),
    last_comment_user_pk=Subquery(last_comment.values('user')[:1])
).prefetch_related('my_wyswietlenia')
```

The `__name` might be different, since it depends on the fields of you `Profil` model.

Then you can render the content and the last author with:

```
{% for post in my_tag %}
    {{ post.last_comment }} by {{ post.last_coment_user }}
{% enfor %}
```

Comment: Can i have one more question? How to create a URL with PK to redirecting to  last comment user profil. Mainly i have with this problem. Main problem is there that this dont read a CommentPost section, and Post.CommentPost.None is back

Comment: @ProtoN: you can annotate the primary key of the last user (see edit) and then use that in calculate the URL.

Comment: you mean last_comment_user?

Comment: @ProtoN: no, `last_comment_user_pk` (see edit, added it to the annotations)

Comment: <span class="forum_tag_author">Stworzony przez » <a href="{% url 'profile:profil_uzytkownika' post.last_comment_user_pk.pk %}">{{ post.last_comment_user }} </a> </span><hr/> return standard reverse error

Comment: no, just `{% url 'profile:profil_uzytkownika' post.last_comment_user_pk %}`.

Comment: I tried this option, and also got standard reverse error ;/

Comment: @ProtoN: did you alter the `.annotate` clause in the view? Note that you should check `{% if post.last_comment_user_pk is not None %} ... {% endif %}`, since there can be items *without* a last comment.